# How to generate QR code together with the image in a center

Tags: node.js, reactjs, qr-code

how I can generate **QR code** in react js or node js?

Maybe you know a library or package for generating QR code together with the image in a center?)

**Example**

[image: Example QR-code]

Answer (score 7):

This function will create qrcode with a logo at centre.

```
const qrcode= require('qrcode');

const getQRcodeImage = async () => {
    try {        
        let canvas=await qrcode.toCanvas(`my sample text`);

        //adding a log at center        
        const imgDim={width:30,height:30}; //logo dimention
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageObj = new Image();  
        imageObj.src = './images/logo.png';        
        imageObj.onload = function() {
          context.drawImage(imageObj, 
          canvas.width / 2 - imgDim.width / 2,
          canvas.height / 2 - imgDim.height / 2,imgDim.width,imgDim.height);
        };        
        return canvas;
    }catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getQRcodeImage().then(res=>{$("#qrcodeAuth").html( res);});
}
```

Comment: This will add an image in the center but just on top of the QR code - obscuring any data in that area and maybe rendering the qr code invalid. Or am I missing something?

Comment: the image is showing in the center for me and i am able to scan the QR code properly.

Comment: @pizzamonster that's how adding a logo to a QR code works... you just obscure part of it and rely on the QR code's forward error correction to handle the missing data. Not nice, but it usually works.